# NSClipView weird background image in NSScrollView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm trying to get a transparent background on my NSTableView, however, it seems as though the NSClipView nestled inside the NSScrollView is causing weird background problems, where it seems it's redrawing the background of the main NSView inside the NSClipView. [image]

I've done all this in an attempt to remove it, but it's just not happening:

```
    [[self.scrollView contentView] setCopiesOnScroll:NO];
    [[self.scrollView contentView] setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [self.scrollView setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [self.scrollView setCopiesOnScroll:NO];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. When creating the background image in the NSView subclass, change the bounds of the drawInRect from dirtyRect to self.bounds. Works a treat.